# Memory layout question

Tags: c++, c, linux, g++

Do these two structs have the same memory layout? (C++)

```
struct A
{
   int x;
   char y;
   double z;
};

struct B
{
   A a;
};
```

Further can I access x, y, z members if I manually cast an object of this to an `A`?

```
struct C
{
   A a;
   int b;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

What if they were `classes` instead of `structs`?

Comment: In C++, classes are the same as structs, except the first defaults to private, the latter to public.

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and yes. The latter is commonly used for emulating OO inheritance in C.

Comment: Are you sure that the first element must to be aligned to the first byte of the structure? I am not. Especially in C++ where the compiler may stick in things like pointers to v-table at any time. Nor am I sure about packing guarantees between such classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can verify this yourself by checking field offsets relative to the start of an instance of each.

```
A aObj;
B bObj;
C cObj;

int xOffset1 = &aObj.x - &aObj;
int xOffset2 = &bObj.a.x - &bObj;

ASSERT(xOffset1 == xOffset2);
```

and so on

Answer (score 2):

$9.2/16- "Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9)."

So the answer is 'yes'

Comment: While OP mentioned C++ in the text of the question, it's also tagged C, so it would be nice to mention that you're citing the C++ standard and not the C standard. Of course the answer is yes for either language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that'll work. Depending on compiler structure packing settings, it may not work with members other than the first.

Comment: @nakiya: I think what Graham means is, if you have a `struct D { char c; A a; };`, then the offset of the member `a` depends on your compiler settings. It's not neccesarily one byte after the beginning of `D`

Comment: The C standard guarantees it works for any common initial subset of struct members.